# SublimeText 2 - find all occurences and save in file

Tags: search, save, sublimetext2

I need to find all occurences of expression in all project files and **saved into a separate file**. (I need complete list of occurences).

It's possible? (If not, please advice made unpaid simple similar editor with this functionality).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this by using Find In Files.  Then paste the output in a separate file and save.

Comment: I know this option, but this is not exactly what i want. ( http://i6.minus.com/ijr2gfqokSdl0.jpg ) --> i must save this big result, and AGAIN separated occurences in one file .. my idea is direct saving the occurences in the file.

Comment: Only the occurrences?  You might be better off writing a small script to scrape them out.

Comment: Yes, PHP script is my second solution, 
but I wanted to know if it ST2 know it  (or with plugin) , probably not.Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: There is another solution.  You can copy all that output file to a new window, and use "Find all" to mark your selections.  Copy those, and then paste again to a new file.